# Ruby on Rails join query condition doesn't work with small limit

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems

I am Writing a an api in rails that will fetch 10 questions for review which have been participated before and have a review level greater then 1.

```
def self.fetch_review_questions(user_id, count, level)
    self.joins(:review_labels)
      .where('review_labels.user_id = ? AND review_labels.level >= level', user_id, level)
      .order("RAND()").limit(count)
  end
```

This function is called from another controller

```
@questions = Question.fetch_review_questions(current_user.id, 10, 2).includes(:choices, :asset)
```

However when this is called, The output contains 10 questions where some of them have the review level of 0.

[image: App side, where question with review level 0 is loaded.]

It may be noted that if I don't use the limit, it works perfectly, which I cannot do.

So, Could anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think `review_labels.level >= level` should read `review_labels.level >= ?`

It surprises me that it appears to work with no limit clause.